# UIAlertView causing change to navigation bar button's titleLabel

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am observing a weird trend in my app: whenever an alert message is displayed, the value of navigation bar button's title gets changed to its storyboard title value. Here is one of the UIAlertView:

[image: navigation bar button title getting changed by alert view]

Title value 100 that is visible in image above is the value that is present in my storyboard. I am successfully changing this bar button's value to whatever is the current score with this line:

```
self.coinsRemainingButton.titleLabel.text = self.coinsRemaining;
```

Everything works fine until I display some alert view. As soon as any UIAlertView is displayed, this navigation bar button's title gets changed to 100 irrespective of the current score. For ex. even if my current score is 500, as soon as an alert message appears my bar button's value gets changed to 100, as shown in screenshot above.
I've checked thoroughly and I am not changing the value mistakenly myself.
If I remove UIAlertView lines everything comes back in order.
Thanks for your time.

Update 1: Here is my UIAlertView code:

```
 UIAlertView *iapSuccessful = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Successful"
                                                            message:@"Congrats!! You just got coins"
                                                           delegate:Nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
 [iapSuccessful show];
```

Update 2: I couldn't find solution so for the sake of workaround I thought of updating my bar button title by code immediately after UIAlertView is displayed:

```
[iapSuccessful show];
self.coinsRemainingButton.titleLabel.text = self.coinsRemaining;
```

but UIAlertView is still forcibly changing title of the bar button to storyboard value.

Comment: shows method where you use uialertview

Comment: @Ilario method is pretty big but I've added my UIAlertView code that am using for alert view.

Comment: I would like to see the piece where add the points, which I guess is just before the UIAlertView

Comment: I am updating coins number by `self.coinsRemainingButton.titleLabel.text = self.coinsRemaining;`. In fact if I monitor that button title attentively then first coins are getting updated to correct number but in a fraction of second, as soon as alert view appears, bar button title gets updated to 100. Note: Points (or coins) can be updated anywhere in flow of the app, not necessarily before any UIAlertView. However every time an alert appears, even if no update to coins number is done anywhere, the coin number in dim background changes to 100.

Comment: there is a point in the code where you say to the coins that have to be 100?

Comment: Nowhere in code I say coins have to be 100. It's just a value I entered when designing storyboard (In utilities->Attribute inspector-->Title). I tried changing value to 200 and rebuild again. And now the value changes to 200 in background whenever any UIAlertView appears. Thanks.

Comment: @SaurabhHooda: Buttons have multiple states, and can have separate titles for each state. I'm guessing the storyboard is setting the same title for several states, and the UIAlertView (for whatever reason) is changing the state of the button. When you set up the button in code instead, you only define the title for the normal state and every other state inherits that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried several tricks to solve this problem but as soon as any `UIAlertView` appears, value (`titleLabel.text`) of the bar button item gets changed to its storyboard value.

I observed that value is getting changed **only** for the navigation bar objects that are drawn from storyboard. So I **removed bar button item from storyboard and added the bar button programmatically and it solved my problem** :)
Here is code for adding bar button item programmatically, if you require:

```
//Add a custom button as the right bar button item of navigation bar
self.coinsRemainingButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.00f, 0.00f, 72.00f, 37.00f);
[self.coinsRemainingButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coinsBackground"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.coinsRemainingButton setTitle:@"100" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *rightCustomBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.coinsRemainingButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightCustomBarButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

removing the title of the button from the storyboard, it solves the problem

Comment: I tried removing title of the button from storyboard but then title of the button is appearing blank when i run my app. Coins are getting updated properly but they are not visible on GUI, title is just blank. `self.coinsRemainingButton.titleLabel.text = self.coinsRemaining;` doesn't seem to work if storyboard title is blank:(

Comment: oh.. strange thing ... in viewDidLoad is declared by how much should this textLabel?

Comment: nothing is mentioned in viewDidLoad pertaining to bar button title. It seems that UIAlertView is resetting navigation bar button items. or at least resetting the values of bar button title to its storyboard value. I tried googling but nothing fruitful...

Comment: @SaurabhHooda if you try to set some value in viewDidLoad? what happens?

Comment: if I set some value in viewDidLoad then that value appears as titleLabel when view loads. but when some alert view appears same issue occurs.

Comment: @SaurabhHooda I know this has nothing to do, but you can change delegate:Nil with delegate:self on UIAlertView?